# Sql server database store procedure query

Tags: sql-server-2017

```
I have two tables as below:

1) UserFavouriteCurrencies

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserFavouriteCurrencies](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
    [CurrencyId] [int] NULL,
    [EntryDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserFavouriteCurrencies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Above table is holding data of user favorite companies

```
2) CurrencyRates

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CurrencyRates](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CurrencyId] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [Open_24h] [float] NULL,
    [Volume_24h] [float] NULL,
    [Low_24h] [float] NULL,
    [High_24h] [float] NULL,
    [Volume_30d] [float] NULL,
    [BestBid] [float] NULL,
    [BestAsk] [float] NULL,
    [TradeId] [bigint] NULL,
    [PriceDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [PriceDateTimestamp] [bigint] NULL,
    [OpenInterest] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CoinbaseTickerRatesMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Above table holds rates details of currencies.

```
Call : EXEC sp_Getdata 1(Here 1 in UserId of UserFavouriteCurrencies table)

I need all records for particular currencies last latest records in one query as below

DECLARE @Today DATETIME = GETDATE(), @PrevDate DATETIME = GETDATE()<br> 

SELECT TOP 1 Price, PriceDate, Volume_24h, PriceDateTimestamp
FROM CurrencyRates
WHERE CurrencyId = @CurrencyId AND PriceDate <= @Today
ORDER BY PriceDateTimestamp DESC
```

Above query is only select data for one particular currency but I need the data related to user which added on UserFavouriteCurrencies table.

Please help me to write store procedure for this query

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

For each currency in `UserFavouriteCurrencies` Table, consider the query below

```
SELECT 
     uc.Id      -- This is the userId
    ,cr.Price
    ,cr.PriceDate,
    ,cr.Volume_24h
    ,cr.PriceDateTimestamp
FROM 
    UserFavouriteCurrencies AS uc 
  INNER JOIN CurrencyRates AS cr   -- See Hints : 1
  ON cr.CurrencyId = uc.CurrencyId
WHERE
   PriceDate <= GETDATE()
  AND
   uc.Id = @Id
   -- You can add other Predicates Here...
```

Hints:

1. Consider using LEFT OUTER JOIN if user's currency may not exist in CurrencyRates
   !This will however introduce NULLs which you must handle